# Pros and Cons of Ajax form validation

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, validation, forms

I see that validating forms using Ajax can be quite useful to avoid code duplication. And before implementing it I am interested if the are any disadvantages of this technique comparing to simple javascript validation. I see only couple of arguments, but I think they are quite weak to take them into account:

1. It's obvious that ajax will increase server load, but it's only 5-6 connections per form which should not be a performance bottleneck.
2. Also I see that js validation can work offline, but as we need to submit a form in the end it can't work without Internet connection anyway.
3. Speed is also not the issue as now broadband is available almost everywhere.

Are there any other arguments that I miss?

Answer (score 2):

Ajax validation is great from a user experience point of view, because you get immediate feedback.

One thing to keep in mind is that even if you validate the form using ajax, you still need to re-validate the submitted values once they hit the server to prevent security exploits, since an attacker could just use something like curl to send arbitrary values.

Comment: Sure, I am just asking if i will validate a form with javascript will I gain anything that I can't with ajax

Comment: @Nutel: AJAX *involves* Javascript. That's what the "J" in "AJAX" stands for.

Comment: @In silico I understand, but it is executed on a client side, so I am curios if there can be any benefits from this feature

Comment: @Nutel: Oh, so are you performing the validation on the server, and using AJAX to send those values for validation without having the user reload the page?

Comment: @Nutel I would consider doing all validation on the server, if I need to query the database or execute other complex logic that would require calling components on the server. Otherwise doing the validation on the client is usually enough and faster.

Comment: @In silico: Yep, I am going to try this practice and just think if I will lose something valuable

Answer (score 1):

If all you're asking is

> I am just asking if i will validate
>   a form with javascript instead of ajax
>   will I gain anything that I can't do with ajax

then no. In the end point - you get a gesture for the user on his bad input.

However, I will not so lightly disregard server load.

5 additional requests per form - to redo on the server checks that it needs to do on form submit - that's about doubling the server work on your forms.

Also - mind that AJAX is also javascript, so you're not completely rid of it.

And last - JavaScript with server roundtrip (and AJAX is a server roundtrip) will not be as immediate as simple JavaScript.

However - yes. it is code duplication. That is your trade of, and any decision you make is valid if your project can take it.

**Edit:** fixed a typo + move to community wiki

Answer (score 1):

To take the contrary position:

1) 5 or 6 requests is no big deal - but 5 or 6 times as many connections per-user per-form - that is.  If you are talking about taking your server from 100k to 600k connections a day, better think about it.

3) Broadband is everywhere, but so are slow and unreliable wireless connections.  Depending on how you implement it, the form could feel very clunky.

And you definitely do need to re-validate on the server - but that's what you are saying: reuse that logic that is on the server anyway, via ajax, instead of replicating it on the client with JS.

Just a side note: Some frameworks allow you to declare validation in one place and then generate the Javascript (non-ajax IIRC) and the server-side for you.   I know JSF (Java Server Faces has this) and I think .net does also.